# How can I validate email in symfony 2.0 (form)

Tags: php, symfony

Could some body help with this?
For symfony 2.0 is no normal documention yet (because it is not stable)

I mean in PHP using symfony

```
class SignupForm extends Form {
    public $email;


    public function configure() {
        $this->add(new TextField('email', array('required' => true)));
    }
}
```

In this code I need add some options, to validate a email field

Comment: So you want to verify an email address as valid?

Comment: Yes, like this `$this->add(new TextField('email', array('validator' => /* some validator class */)));`, but this doesn't works, it thows exception 'validator' is unknown options

Answer (score 2):

never used it but did find some info @ http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/constraints/Email.html

```
properties:
    email:
        - Email: ~
```

a normal check with php5 would be something like this:

```
    if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
  echo "Valid email address.";
    }else {
    echo "Invalid email address.";
    }
```

php-4-5

```
    if(eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$",$email)) {
    echo "Valid email address.";
    }else {
    echo "Invalid email address.";
    }
```

Comment: I mean in PHP using Symfony, in `class SignupForm extends Form { function configure() {} }`

Comment: Validation constraints are added to Entities (the model), not the forms.